# APT Repository is Not Signed Error, But It's Not Even Installed - Wine

Tags: apt, updates, wine, repository

I just removed the Wine application, and all of its files, from my system. It was installed with the `https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease` repository. I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and the repository is not listed there.

Whenever I run `sudo apt update`, I get the following error:

```
The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
```

Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish

Comment: Most likely it is a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` which need to be removed, check it out.

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a file in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory that you can remove. This could have happened because of a number of reasons, like maybe a strange installation, strange uninstallation, or weird removal of the repository.

There should be a file similar to `wine.list` or something containing the word "wine" in it (maybe `wine-builds.list`, just guessing from the repository name).

Comment: This is technically correct however the file can be something like "winehq-jammy.sources" as well.

Comment: Same as previous response. Go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and locate the `winehq-<release>.sources` and delete it. This will do the trick. **If it throws an access denied error, try it with root privilages.**
`sudo rm -rf winehq-<release>.sources` Make sure you replace the `<release>` with whatever the version that shows in your directory. Example: `winehq-jammy.sources`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I never installed wine.

Fix it :

cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d

rm -f winehq-bionic.sources

Comment: This helped me solve the issue but does not explain why, my filename was winehq-jammy.sources for anyone reading later.